# LOAD DATA INFILE with txt file

Tags: mysql, sql, load-data-infile

i have txt file containing more than 50000 records.those 4 records (pid,#_pro_used,notused,selected) are separate with tab space.i want to insert these records to a table which having 5 columns (index,pid,#_pro_used,notused,selected)..Extra one (index) column should be the primary key containing count of the record.

i have used this command..but its not working.

```
  LOAD DATA LOCAL INFILE 'D:/temp.txt' INTO TABLE temp_table    (COUNT(pid),pid,#_pro_used,notused,selected);
```

Is this possible? or i should go for a trigger?

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow! When you say it is not working, please give any detailed error message you're receiving as well as giving the structure of the table you're trying to load in to, and a few lines of the source data to help us help you.

Comment: here is it--Error Code : 1064
You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that    corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use    near 'Count(pid),pid,#_pro_used,notused,selected)' at line 1

Comment: is it possible to use LOAD DATA INFILE command to insert a column which is not in the data importing source..if its not then how can i do it.please help

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can't use COUNT(pid) to count the number of entries inserted that far. Create a table with an auto-increment column and skip the "COUNT(pid)" part, so:

```
CREATE TABLE temp_table (
  idx INT UNSIGNED AUTO_INCREMENT PRIMARY KEY,
  pid ...
  pro_used ...
  notused
  selected
);

LOAD DATA LOCAL INFILE 'D:/temp.txt'
INTO TABLE temp_table (pid,pro_used,notused,selected);
```

Just a note: you have a column called "notused", which I assume that you want to ignore. You can just use a user-defined variable here, which will then just throw the data away:

```
LOAD DATA LOCAL INFILE 'D:/temp.txt'
INTO TABLE temp_table (pid,pro_used,@notused,selected);
```

Comment: Still it displays an error                                               You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near '' at line 1

Comment: LOAD DATA LOCAL INFILE 'D:/temp.txt' 
INTO TABLE temp_table
(pid,#_pro_used,notused,selected);

Comment: create table command    -                                                  


CREATE TABLE `temp_table` (
  `indexid` int(11) unsigned NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `pid` varchar(5) NOT NULL,
  `#_pro_used` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
  `notused` double DEFAULT NULL,
  `selected` double DEFAULT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`indexid`)
)

Comment: You can't use # as part of an identifier (that is, not without using backquotes).

Comment: now its working.. dont know how to say thanks..you saved me. thank you very much